# I'm confused about behavior of `store.filter` method in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js

I'm a little confused about behavior of Ember Data.

Please look at this sample: http://jsbin.com/ETEwUxU/9/edit .
Click 'Go to Active', then Click 'Go to Index'. Please repeat this navigation over and over again.
And check Javascript console of your browser.

My questions are...

1. Why is the `store.filter`'s function called when we go to `index` Route?
2. Why do the number of `store.filter`'s function call go on increasing as we repeat above?
3. Why the number of `store.filter`'s function call grow when we discomment `store.find('post');` in the model hook of `ActiveRoute`?

Is this behavior a feature of Ember Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the record is added to another record array it triggers the filter array to recheck if the filter is up to date:

> **
>       Takes a type and filter function, and returns a live RecordArray that
>       remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created
>       locally.

And you keep creating live record arrays each time you hit the route, all are keeping up to date every time you call find.

You can move the posts down one level and fetch them on the posts resource, and store the filter at that level.  Then you when you hit the active route you can fetch the filtered list from the controller above him.

AKA PostsActiveController get the filtered resultset from the PostsController.

http://jsbin.com/OCAKIjA/4/edit

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, What should I do?
I do not want the filter function to be called unnecessarily.
Is there any best practice in these cases?

Comment: I would grab the resource and store it on the controller above the route. (that way you can bounce back and forth the the index/active route) without refetching the filtered list.  You could also store the posts for the index route and avoid having to hit the store for that as well, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful to me. I'd like to try the latter.